# Trying to fill an array with user input

Tags: c++

I've bumped into a problem. I'm trying to store user entered values into an array until they enter -1 by using a do-while loop. Here's a sample of my code:

```
int j=0;
    do{
        cin >> nodes[j];
        j++;
    }
    while (nodes[j] != -1);
```

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work and what a better approach would be? Thanks!

Comment: Isn`t `j` already incremented when the comparison `nodes[j] != -1` is made?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you've increment end the index (j) after receiving input and before reading input. You could instead compare nodes[j-1] == -1

Also important, you might overrun your array if you don't put in a maximum number of elements.

Comment: Thanks! I have a max number of elements for that array earlier up in my function so no worries! T

Comment: You need to abort the loop when that max is hit, even if -1 hasn't been provided... Easy to do that, by terminating on -1 || j == max

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `j` already incremented when the comparison `nodes[j] != -1` is made?

Also, I presume, that we do not want to store the *sentinel* value `-1` into the array.

```
for( int j = 0; j != NodeMax; ++j) {
    int tmp = 0;
    cin >> tmp;
    if( tmp == -1 ) {
        break;
    }
    node[ j ] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Arun mentioned, `j` is already increased when `nodes[j] != -1` is checked.

Modify as follows:

```
do {
    cin >> nodes[j];
} while (nodes[j++] != -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `while (nodes[j] != -1);` will never be true because you are incrementing `j` and moving on the the next index before checking the value. A better approach would be this:

```
do{
    cin >> nodes[j];
}
while (j < SIZE && nodes[j++] != -1);
```

Comment: Now j is incremented twice in one loop!

Answer (score 0):

`nodes[j]` isn't the `nodes[j]` you enter since it has been `++`,
try this:
`while(cin>>node[j++]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing j before node[j]!=-1 check.
Either do this

```
int j=-1;
    do{
        j++;
        cin >> nodes[j];

    }
    while (nodes[j] != -1);
```

or

```
int j=0;
        do{

            cin >> nodes[j];

        }
        while (nodes[j++] != -1);
```

or

```
int j=0;
while(cin>>nodes[j] && nodes[j]!=-1)
{
     j++;
}
```